# Why do Eigen values not show the correct type?

Tags: c++, eigen

I currently have a project I am working on and for some reason every time I have this function being called the eigen value type shown in my debugger will be shown as a Matrix when it was declared as a vector. Why is this the case?

```
double project::General_Table_Lookup(const Eigen::VectorXd& indep_params,
                                const std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd>& breakpoints,
                                const array_type& data_table, const bool& clip_inputs,
                                Eigen::VectorXi& indices)
```

If I put a breakpoint right in the beginning of the function my debugger will declare these parameters as follows:

```
+       indep_params    {...}   const Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> &
+       breakpoints { size=??? }    const std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>,std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>>> &

+       indices {...}   Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,1,0,-1,1> &
```

I have literally tried everything that I could think of but was unsuccessful to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Eigen::Vector` is a typedef of an [Eigen::Matrix that has exactly one column](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga2623c0d4641dda067fbdb9a009ef0c91).

Your debugger is correct.